# Assistance with building regex

Tags: regex, perl

I hate doing this but I've banged my head for hours just trying to figure out regexes, so I am finally resorting to asking the experts.

```
-1,AAABO,ABOAO
-2,ABBBO,BABBO
-3,AAACO,ACAAO
-4,ABDDO,BADDO
-5,AAABF,ABFAA
-6,BBBGO,BGBBO
```

I am looking to match multiple substrings but only between the commas.

For example:

```
AA and B would return rows 1,5
BB and O would return 2 and 6
BBB and G would return row 6
AA C and O would return row 3
```

I would build this dynamically as needed.

The 2nd step would be filtering on the beginning or end of the string after the 2nd comma

For example (start):

```
AB would return row 1 and 5
```

For example (end):

```
BO would return row 2 and 6
```

and then I need to combine all 3 filters.

For example

```
AAA O (contains from 2nd column)
AB    (begins with)
O     (ends with)
```

returns row 1

I could do multiple passes if required.

I would be delighted with any guidance.

Comment: What tool are you using?

Comment: @e0k i'll be using PERL

Comment: Why would `AA` and `B` return line 2? Also, does `AA C and O` means `AA` and `C` and `O`?

Comment: Fixed the question to remove the 2.  Yes AA C and O, the string would need to have all 3

Comment: What I am struggling with is how to capture the entire string and do a substring match

Comment: The trick is not to try to "build a regex" to solve the problem. If you take away that constraint, it's easily done in a few lines of code.

Comment: I suppose it could, it just seems like a good candidate for regex, and could get done in 1 line of code.

Comment: Even I don't understand what are you trying and if your substrings must be in that order try something like [this](http://rubular.com/r/Hh7ZgTVFaA) just make sure that you have `.*` at the beginning, at the end, and between substrings, and test all of your array elements against your pattern. All combinations from your example return correct rows (if I'm not wrong).

Comment: Unless I'm missing something (which is entirely possible), this isn't any more difficult than `split` on `/,/` and correctly using the start and end anchors `^` and `$`. Have you tried that yet? What _have_ you tried so far? (Banging your head for hours doesn't count.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the regex

```
/^.*?,(?=[^,]*AAA)(?=[^,]*O).*?,AB.*O$/
```

with commentary

```
/ 
    ^.*?,           # consume the first field
    (?=[^,]*AAA)    # look ahead in the 2nd field for AAA
    (?=[^,]*O)      # look ahead in the 2nd field for O
    .*?,            # consume the 2nd field
    AB.*O$          # the 3rd field starts with AB and ends with O
/x
```

which you can generate like this

```
sub gen_regex {
    my ($begins, $ends, @contains) = @_;
    my $regex = "^.*?," 
              . join("", map {"(?=[^,]*$_)"} @contains) 
              . ".*?,$begins.*$ends\$";
    return qr/$regex/;
}

my $re = gen_regex('AB', 'O', qw(AAA O));
```

and then use it like this:

```
while (<>) { say $. if /$re/ }
```

Comment: With a few tweaks, it worked brilliantly.  It almost looks comically easy once you see it.  But I know better!  Thank-you!